# How to test predicate in an unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel, junit5

I have an Apache Camel application, which uses a [Choice](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.16.x/eips/choice-eip.html) with a [Predicate](https://camel.apache.org/manual/predicate.html). How can I test the predicate without an integration test?

**Code**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  public EndpointRouteBuilder route() {
    return new EndpointRouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(file("d:/tmp/camel/"))
            .choice()
            .when(jsonpath("$[?(@.status == 0)]"))
            .log("ok")
            .otherwise()
            .log("not ok");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**Research**

- I read [Test JUnit5](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/others/test-junit5.html), but it looks like an integration test. However, I don't want to test a full route.
- I read [Test Spring JUnit5](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/others/test-spring-junit5.html), but it is an integration test.

**Question**

How can I extract the predicate `jsonpath("$[?(@.status == 0)]")` and test it isolated in an unit test with JUnit 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be hard to accomplish this without a CamelContext. I'd probably approach this with Camel's excellent [mocking](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/others/test-spring-junit5.html) and [stubbing](https://camel.apache.org/manual/advice-with.html) utilities. But if you really just want to isolate the jsonpath expression, you could try something like this:

```java
JsonPathExpression exp = new JsonPathExpression("$[?(@.status == 0)]");
Exchange exchange = new DefaultExchange(context);
final Predicate predicate = exp.createPredicate(context);
exchange.getIn().setBody("{ \"status\": 0 }");
final boolean matches = predicate.matches(exchange);
assertTrue(matches);
```

Note that you'll still need a CamelContext for this. Typically you'd get it by having the test class extend CamelTestSupport, or if you're in a spring environment, spring can autowire it: `@Autowired CamelContext camelContext;`

Edit: If you just want to test the JsonPath expression outside of Camel:

```java
String jsonPath = "$[?(@.status == 0)]";
String json = "{ \"status\": 0 }";

DocumentContext jsonContext = JsonPath.parse(json);
JSONArray result = jsonContext.read(jsonPath);
assertEquals(1, result.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

My opinion (you'll probably get 100 more ;-)

Separate that route into another class by itself that can be loaded into the Spring context later.

Use CamelTestSupport to load just Camel (not Spring) in JUnit.

Use Camel "advice" to change "from" to a direct, or create a file (in your test) to exercise the test case you want (once with each branch of the choice.

Again with "advice" change the log to mocks - then after running the file/message you want check to see if the correct mock got a message and the other did not.

Answer (score 0):

I do as below

```
@CamelSpringTest
public class TemporaryErrorPredicateTest {

    @Mock
    private Exchange exchange;

    @InjectMocks
    private TemporaryErrorPredicate predicate;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("exceptionAndStatusCodeProvider")
    public void shouldReturnTrueOn500Error(int statusCode) {
        when(exchange.getException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)).thenReturn(new HttpOperationFailedException("Temporary Error", statusCode, null, null, null, null));

        assertTrue(predicate.matches(exchange));
    }

    private static Stream<Arguments> exceptionAndStatusCodeProvider() {
        return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR),
            Arguments.of(HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY),
            Arguments.of(HTTP_UNAVAILABLE),
            Arguments.of(HTTP_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)
        );
    }
}
```

for a predicate like

```
@Component
public class TemporaryErrorPredicate implements Predicate {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Exchange exchange) {
        HttpOperationFailedException exception = exchange.getException(HttpOperationFailedException.class);
        int httpResponseCode = exception.getStatusCode();
        return switch (httpResponseCode){
            case HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR,HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY,HTTP_UNAVAILABLE,HTTP_GATEWAY_TIMEOUT ->  true;
            default ->  false;
        };
    }
}
```